# Upgraded to TS 2.4. Webpack isn't seeing my @types anymore

Tags: typescript, typescript2.4

I recently upgraded to TSC 2.4

```
yarn add typescript@2.4
```

When I run `webpack`, I get a large number of errors (that were not there in 2.3) for missing modules that have `@types` in my `package.json`:

```
ERROR in /home/rick/code/farmbot/frontend/tsconfig.json
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
```

The example above is missing a typing for "node", but it is also happening for jest, mqtt, handlebars and many others.

Has management of type definitions changed in TS 2.4?

**Additional info** Restarting Webpack did not help.

Comment: Considering they essentially managed to break half the definitely-typed registry (and 4 of our build pipelines) with a single update, I'm amazed it works at all. `</rant>` We simply fixed ourselves to 2.3 until they get it together.

Comment: Does that really happen for any project with Webpack? Which version of webpack are you using? Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a problem with Webpack but with your @types/node package, can you try to upgrade it too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16772#issuecomment-311761959, this is an issue with ts-loader. Upgrading to ts-loader@2.2.1 should resolve the issue.